# Boolean properties in c#

Tags: c#, .net, boolean

This might be a dumb question, but the property below, will there ever be a situation where just getting it will cause an exception?

Like if I did something like `bool value = this.BatchValuation;` - but I hadn't set `BatchValuation` yet, will it just set `value` to `null`, or will it cause an exception?

```
public bool BatchValuation { get; set; }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> This might be a dumb question

It is not.

> in the property below, will there ever be a situation where just getting it will cause an exception?

Possibly, yes. For example, another thread could abort your thread while it was in the middle of fetching that property; that would appear to be an exception thrown by the property getter. Or, you could run out of stack space right at the moment where the property is called, and an out-of-stack exception could be thrown. Or, when you call the property for the first time, the jitter might start up and try to allocate virtual memory for the generated code, but you are all out of virtual address space, so an out of memory exception could be thrown.

Those are all extraordinarily unlikely, but they are all *possible*. You asked if there would *ever* be such a situation, not if it was *likely*.

> If I hadn't set BatchValuation yet, will it just set value to null, or will it cause an exception?

Neither; it will default to *false*. Booleans are not nullable.

Comment: This is truly what I was asking, so you get the answer.

Answer (score 29):

boolean values default to false if you have not set them specifically. So no there will be no exception, the property will just return false.

Remember that this is a value type we are talking about, only variables for reference types can be set to `null`. Value types do have a default value, which is zero for numeric types and false for boolean.

Also see [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Comment: Okay perfect this is what I thought I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Automatic properties e.g. { get; set; } generate the fields for you, those fields contain the default values, in the case of a boolean, the default is false (you can use default(sometype) to find out what the default is for that type)

Answer (score 3):

no, Boolean defaults to false. So

```
bool something; // something is false
```

Answer (score 3):

In the context of *class properties or member fields*, each field is initialized to a default value for the type when the class is created *prior* to the constructor being run. In the class

```
class Foo
{
    bool bar;
    string s;
    int item;
    public double Baz { get; set; } 
}
```

The first three fields are set to their initial values (false, null, and 0, respectively), and the auto-generated backing field for `Baz` is also set to 0.0d. It is not an error to access these fields/properties without explicit user-initialization, unlike accessing uninitialized locals. It is for locals that the compiler requires explicit initialization.

```
class Foo
{
   int bar;

   void M()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(bar); // not an error, bar is 0;
       bool someBool;
       Console.WriteLine(someBool); // use of uninitialized local variable
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As BrokenGlass said, the boolean values default to false,

you can test it by yourself, I provide a sample as below.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create an object, but don't set attribute.
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        if (!foo.BatchValuation)
            Console.WriteLine("BatchValuation is False");

        else
            Console.WriteLine("BatchValuation is True");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}


// Test class.
public class Foo
{
    private bool _batchValuation;
    public Foo() { }
    public bool BatchValuation 
    {
        get { return _batchValuation; }
        set { _batchValuation = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a very weird situation, when auto-implemented property like this threw a `NullReferenceException` exception. The reason was Emit Mappper library (http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/).

This library (which is very good otherwise) uses  Refleciton.Emit and, when it sees no public constructor for the type, it emits mapping call sites, which pass null reference as implied first argument of property/method (which ends up as "this" in all instance methods).

So the property was trying to change field value of a null reference (that is, I had `this==null` situation)!